# Android SQLite execSQL problems

Tags: android, sqlite

**LogCat:**

```
 04-26 22:46:31.940  32461-32461/com.elnaggar.blooddonation
 E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "Request": syntax error 04-26 22:46:31.970 
 32461-32461/com.elnaggar.blooddonation E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
 EXCEPTION: main
     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Request": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Donation Request(_id
 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, _full_address TEXT NOT NULL,
 _description TEXT NOT NULL, _contact_info TEXT NOT NULL,_area TEXT NOT NULL, _blood_type TEXT NOT NULL);
             at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
 Method)
```

**Code:**

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROW_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, " + KEY_FULL_ADDRESS
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_CONTACT_INFO + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_AREA
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_BLOOD_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL);");


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table name: `Donation Request` consists of 2 words while there can be only one. Replace: `Donation Request` with `DonationRequest`

Comment: Thanks man I already did that and I but _ between the tow world
I appreciate your answer

Comment: OR (**not recommended**) use square brackets to use spaced words. I.e.: `[Donation Request]`.